# CSS top right icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a loop that shows all the users comments. I'm trying to add a trash icon on the top-right of each comment, but it's putting all the icons at the same place in one div. I don't want the icon to change the position of the comments and that's why I did position absolute, but it's not working.

Loop code:

```
<div class="col-md-5 all">
 <div class="col-md-12 hello">
  @foreach($comment as $comments)
   @if($comments->image_id == $image->id)
    <div id="{{$comments->id}}" class="ajaxrules">

     <div class="col-md-2"> 
       <img src="{{$comments->user_avatar}}" class="img-circle buddy">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10">
      <h4>{!! $image->user_name !!}</h4>
      <p class="left">{!!$comments->body!!} </p>
     </div>
     <div class="deletecomment">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
     </div> 
   </div>
   @endif
  @endforeach 
  <div class="addavatar">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .deletecomment{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   clear:both;

}

.addavatar, .ajaxrules{
   padding-right: 60px; 
   padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Absolute makes them all in that spot. Position relative.

Comment: If I do relative it messes my comments because it's taking space

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with the html and css you need. Then we can actually see what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `position: relative`

to `.ajaxrules`

So the trash icon will be absolute to it's parent

**Edit**: adding additional information on position absolute/relative

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Yeah, I did it, but then they are sitting right under each other at the top, they are not spreading to each comment.

Comment: @ItzikBenHutta then do you mind maybe putting your code in a jsfiddle with an example comment so we could debug it easier?

Comment: Probably should of been a comment. Link only answers are bad. And this did not answer his problem.

Comment: @Hanoncs you are probably right, I should've commented, but I think it's not my answer what's wrong here, it contains a fix for it (given the example code that OP gave) and a link to documentation about how relative and absolute positions work (which is easy to find with a simple google)